# Vimeo - How to upload private videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using the official node.js module to upload videos to Vimeo which can be found [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js).

I am able to upload videos without any problem. However, I find that the uploaded videos are public. Anybody can access them.

How do I make the videos private. My account has both public and private videos. I wish that the videos that I upload through my application automatically become private.

I could not find a mention of this in the API documents and in the documentation for the above Node.js module that I am using to upload videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. All uploaded videos respect your global privacy settings. This includes API uploads. You can learn more [here](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/managing-your-videos/privacy-settings#how-do-i-change-the-privacy-on-all-my-videos-at-once).
2. You can make a video private after it has been uploaded (and before, or after it has been transcoded). Check out the docs [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D). Specifically you want to edit the privacy.view key.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer:

```
var client = new Vimeo(config.client_id, config.client_secret, config.access_token)
```

```
  var params = {
    'name': 'Vimeo API SDK test upload',
    'description': "This video was uploaded through the Vimeo API's NodeJS SDK.",
    'privacy':{
      'view' : "nobody"
    }
  }
```

```
client.upload(
        filePath,
        params,
        function (uri) {
          // Get the metadata response from the upload and log out the Vimeo.com url
          client.request(uri + '?fields=link', function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('There was an error making the request.')
              console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
              return
            }

            console.log('"' + filePath + '" has been uploaded to ' + body.link)
        }
```

The other values for `privacy.view` are: anybody | contacts | disable | nobody | password | unlisted | users*.

For further info you can visit [this page](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos).